# Adding sub domain based routes in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, routes, router

I am newbie to Zend framework, I am  using .ini file to add routes in my application.

I have 2 routes for different modules which

```
resources.router.routes.news_view.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.news_view.route = "([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.html"
resources.router.routes.news_view.defaults.module = "news"
resources.router.routes.news_view.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.news_view.defaults.action = "view"
resources.router.routes.news_view.map.1 = "date"
resources.router.routes.news_view.map.2 = "title"

resources.router.routes.edu_view.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.edu_view.route = "([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.html"
resources.router.routes.edu_view.defaults.module = "education"
resources.router.routes.edu_view.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.edu_view.defaults.action = "article"
resources.router.routes.edu_view.map.1 = "date"
resources.router.routes.edu_view.map.2 = "title"
```

the url pattern is like

```
http://news.mysite.com/27-08-09/sample.html

http://education.mysite.com/27-08-09/sample.html
```

the problem I face is the last defined route is assigned for both the modules.

can anyone suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi after much browsing in the web I came up with this solution for my problem

```
resources.router.routes.www.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.www.route = ":module.findchennai.com"
resources.router.routes.www.defaults.module = "www"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

The above code maps the module with sub domain

```
resources.router.routes.news.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.news.route = "news.findchennai.com"
resources.router.routes.news.defaults.module = "news"

resources.router.routes.edu.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.edu.route = "education.findchennai.com"
resources.router.routes.edu.defaults.module = "education"

resources.router.routes.edu.chains.list.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.edu.chains.list.route = ":categ/:page"
resources.router.routes.edu.chains.list.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.edu.chains.list.defaults.action = "category"
resources.router.routes.edu.chains.list.defaults.page = 1

resources.router.routes.news.chains.list.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.news.chains.list.route = ":categ/:page"
resources.router.routes.news.chains.list.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.news.chains.list.defaults.action = "category"
resources.router.routes.news.chains.list.defaults.page = 1
```

This solves the problem I faced and now could map correctly to the following urls

```
http://news.mysite.com/27-08-09/sample.html
http://education.mysite.com/27-08-09/sample.html
```

Still if some one knows how to optimise the above code further, Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do both subdomains call into the same index.php?

If they don't only set the route based on the appropriate sub domain instead of setting both routes in both sub domains.

If they do either read from the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variable and set the correct route based on the subdomain or set an environment variable in your .htaccess file so you can tell which subdomain you are in.

Comment: Hi,
I have added a separate route which maps the sub domain and routes to it.
resources.router.routes.www.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.www.route = ":module.mysite.com"
resources.router.routes.www.defaults.module = "www"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"

Comment: Please add that as the answer.