# Zend framework on subdomain

Tags: zend-framework

How do I setup Zend framework on sub domain manually?

What setting do I have to change in the bootstrap file?

Comment: I have done this before. You shouldn't have to do anything different, just make sure your paths are correct. Try it then come back when you have an actual problem that needs solving.

Comment: Thanks Jakenoble

I have already done.Actully me domain was not activated.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what exactly do you need? if you need to recognize subdomain use router settings

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

[Adding sub domain based routes in Zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340467/adding-sub-domain-based-routes-in-zend-framework)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837983/zend-framework-subdomainsubfolder-router-rewrite-problem